# Query for getting comma separated data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I still strugling with creation of mysql query where I want to do something like:

My table's name is called **orders**, structure is like:

```
id | price | kind | orderdate
-----------------------------
1  |  35   | 2    | 2013-01-01
2  |  30   | 2    | 2013-01-02
3  |  25   | 2    | 2013-01-03
4  |  15   | 2    | 2013-01-03
```

I don't know how to get comma separated data like: **1, 1, 2** where this numbers are count of rows in particular orderdate. So further if I'll want example "count of orders" from every day between in two monts I'll have comma separated array of 60 values. I will pass data from date array so I need to get 0 value if in particular orderdate is nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the date and then you can use count the get the number of records for every date. If you want that in a single row then use `group_concat`

```
select group_concat(count(*) separator ', ') as counts
from orders
group by orderdate
order by orderdate
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but sorry I havent completly posted my requirements... I will have order date from variable so I need to get 0 value if in particular day is found nothing.

Comment: I will have array like `2013-01-01,2013-01-02,2013-01-03,2013-01-04,2013-01-05` so If I change it instead orderdate in `group by` row, will I get 5 values ? Like in this case 1,1,2,0,0 ?

Comment: No, you will not. A DB is designed to get existing values, not missing values. You better select what you have and add the rest in your logic.